# Adding AIDL to AOSP build

Tags: java, android, android-source

I'm want to add method `test` to `ILocationManager` with listener argument, so I've created a listener:

```
oneway interface ITestListener {
    void onTest(String provider);
}
```

And the `ILocationManager` method:

```
    void test(ITestListener listener);
```

While building (both `m` and `m update-api`) I'm getting error for generated code:

```
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:13: error: Missing nullability on method `asBinder` return [MissingNullability]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:18: error: Raw AIDL interfaces must not be exposed: Stub extends Binder [RawAidl]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:81: error: Registration methods should have overload that accepts delivery Executor: `setDefaultImpl` [ExecutorRegistration]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:26: error: Missing nullability on method `asInterface` return [MissingNullability]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:30: error: Missing nullability on parameter `obj` in method `asInterface` [MissingNullability]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:41: error: Missing nullability on method `asBinder` return [MissingNullability]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:45: error: Methods calling system APIs should rethrow `RemoteException` as `RuntimeException` (but do not list it in the throws clause) [RethrowRemoteException]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:45: error: Missing nullability on parameter `data` in method `onTransact` [MissingNullability]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:45: error: Missing nullability on parameter `reply` in method `onTransact` [MissingNullability]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:81: error: Missing nullability on parameter `impl` in method `setDefaultImpl` [MissingNullability]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:94: error: Missing nullability on method `getDefaultImpl` return [MissingNullability]Error: metalava detected the following problems:
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:13: error: Missing nullability on method `asBinder` return [MissingNullability]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:18: error: Raw AIDL interfaces must not be exposed: Stub extends Binder [RawAidl]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:81: error: Registration methods should have overload that accepts delivery Executor: `setDefaultImpl` [ExecutorRegistration]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:26: error: Missing nullability on method `asInterface` return [MissingNullability]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:30: error: Missing nullability on parameter `obj` in method `asInterface` [MissingNullability]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:41: error: Missing nullability on method `asBinder` return [MissingNullability]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:45: error: Methods calling system APIs should rethrow `RemoteException` as `RuntimeException` (but do not list it in the throws clause) [RethrowRemoteException]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:45: error: Missing nullability on parameter `data` in method `onTransact` [MissingNullability]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:45: error: Missing nullability on parameter `reply` in method `onTransact` [MissingNullability]
out/srcjars/android/location/ITestListener.java:81: error: Missing nullability on parameter `impl` in method `setDefaultImpl` [MissingNullability]
```

But it's generated code — how to fix it?